# Parse lists in pandas columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, types

I am trying to figure out how to parse pandas columns containing lists: my problem is that these are recognised as strings, whereas I would like them to be treated as lists, to iterate through them.

This is an example of my cells: `[('P105', 1), ('P31', 1), ('P225', 1), ('P70', 1)]`

When I try to iterate through it, I only get the characters contained in the string one by one (i.e. [, (, ', P etc.). 
How do I make pandas 'understand' that these are lists?

Edit: I have found a way to do that: I apply `ast.literal_eval` to each line.

Example:

```
line = month_statement['properties_claims'][12]
for i in line:
    print i

[
(
'
P
7
6
'
...
```

If I use `ast.literal_eval`, instead:

```
line = ast.literal_eval(month_statement['properties_claims'][12])
line
Out[23]: 
[('P76', 1),
 ('P77', 1),
 ('P75', 1),
 ('P273', 1),
 ('P70', 1),
 ('P107', 1),
 ('P225', 1)]
```

My doubt now is how efficient this approach will be to process millions of lines.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are doing. If you save the above as a list, then make it into a DataFrame, you get two columns. You can then happily iterate between each one as you please. ie      pd.DataFrame( [('P105', 1), ('P31', 1), ('P225', 1), ('P70', 1)])

Comment: I have a data frame of which two columns were saved as python lists. To run my analysis, I have to select the tuples in each row's lists in which an element is present, e.g.:  finding P105 in [('P105', 1), ('P31', 1), ('P225', 1), ('P70', 1)]. 
Now the problem is that I cannot iterate through the list, but only through its characters.

Answer (score 11):

pretty old question, but i guess this should work:

```
import ast

df['col'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

read data into chunks if file is too big, using e.g. `pd.read_csv(...,cunksize=50000)`

Answer (score 4):

I would personally split that into further columns and iterate over them:

```
   df['col'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x.split(',')))
```

or

```
   df['col'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series( x.replace( '),' , ')&&' ).split('&&')))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this splits also the tuples within the lists. I will try to change it, in order to avoid that.

Comment: @Aliossandro try:    df['col'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series( x.replace(   '),'   ,    ')&&' ).split('&&')))